# PHP Form POST automated. Your ideas?

Tags: php, forms, post, cookies, automation

This isn't a real code problem but more a where and how to start problem.
So I hope you can give me some creative ideas, examples or share your thoughts !

After login in to a website, I can change my product details, this is done by HTTP POST forms.
Because we have over 1000 products I somehow want to customise / easyify.

My idea was, make a PHP form on my own server which submits to the supplier url(s).
However when doing this, it forwards us to the customer login.

If I temper my submitted data in firefox, I see this is because after login a cookie is been set and obvious our system does not have this.

Anyone an idea how to automate this process ? In other words, how can I set this cookie in my php form in order to submit it succesfully.

Or Im I thinking about the wrong solution ?!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post to another server unless you use cURL or something like that. Maybe I am not understanding your question.

Comment: You are understanding my question right. I did not know you can not crossdomain php post. :-(
Let's search for an curl example, I guess that would be the right direction to think of.

Comment: Alternative : 

One of them is using PHP€™s functions fsockopen() and fputs() to send properly formatted data to a remote server.